# Separate list elements into groups of two in all possible ways?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, combinatorics

Consider a list with an even number of elements, e.g.

```
list = {1,2,3,4};
```

I would like to have a function `fun` that produces all possible ways the elements could be arranged in unordered groups of two, so that for example

```
fun[list]
```

> `{ {{1,2},{3,4}} , {{1,3},{2,4}} , {{1,4},{2,3}} }`

While for the example of length 4 above the decomposition is kind of trivial, for longer examples it becomes more cumbersome. Is there a way to do this efficiently in Mathematica?

Answer (score 0):

```
DeleteDuplicates[
 Sort[
 (Sort /@ Partition[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[list, {Length[list]}])]
 ]
```

Comment: This produces way too many elements. But the answer to the question linked by Carl Woll seems to do the trick.